# Java MYSQL Exception in executeQuery()

Tags: java, mysql, exception, executequery

I get a Java MySQL exception

```
@Override

public ResultSet executeQuery (String query, ArrayList<Argument> arguments) throws SQLException
{
    final PreparedStatement pstmt = getPstmt(query, arguments);
    final ResultSet retrievedData = pstmt.executeQuery();
    return retrievedData;
}




//getpstmt()

private PreparedStatement getPstmt (String query, ArrayList<Argument> arguments) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);

            if (arguments != null) {
                int argPosition = 1;
                for (final Argument arg : arguments) {
                    if (arg.getType() == ARGUMENT_TYPE.INTEGER) {
                        pstmt.setInt(argPosition++, arg.getInt());
                    }
                    else {
                        pstmt.setString(argPosition++, arg.getString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (final Exception ex) {
            NmsLogger.writeDebugLog(ex);
            return null;
        }

        return pstmt;

    }



// One instance of calling executeQuery

public String getProperty(String propertyName) 
    {

        try 
        {
            ArrayList<Argument> arguments = new ArrayList<Argument>();
            arguments.add(new Argument(propertyName));

            final java.sql.ResultSet resultset = Application.getDBHandler().executeQuery(SQLQueries.GET_PROPERTY, null);
            Application.getDBHandler().executeQuery(SQLQueries.GET_PROPERTY, arguments);
            if(resultset.next())
            {
                resultset.getString(1);

            }
            return resultset.toString();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            NmsLogger.writeDebugLog(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**I get the following error when I debug the following code :**

java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Someone do suggest a way to solve..Why I get such an exception?

Comment: can you post your query and also the code in `getPstmt`?

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo I have edited the question.. Hope u get it now.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint at `for (final Argument arg : arguments) {` and see if `arguments` is empty?

Comment: can you show us an example query that you're running?

Comment: GET_PROPERTY is an example query.    
 
public static final String GET_PROPERTY = "Select * from app_config where Property = ? ";

Comment: it skips the first parameter of your prepared statement. see my answer below.

Comment: ArrayList<Argument> arguments = new ArrayList<Argument>();
   arguments.add(new Argument(name));
   arguments.add(new Argument(value));

Application.getDBHandler().executeQuery(SQLQueries.GET_PROPERTY, arguments);



These are the argument list and values I send

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `null` to executeQuery instead of list of arguments here:

```
Application.getDBHandler().executeQuery(SQLQueries.GET_PROPERTY, null);
```

So, the no value in the place of `?` in the query `"Select * from app_config where Property = ?"`, hence the exception.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Senthil Thanks.this helped and there were few other changes.:) Its clear now